# Installing DFS role in Windows2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

I have 2008 R2 server with existing File server, IIS & Application server roles. But, DFS was not selected while installing File server role. Can we add this feature in existing file server role or I have to complete remove that role & then re-install along with DFS feature

Thanks,

Sandesh

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install the DFS role after installing the other roles

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add both the DFS Replication and DFS Namespace services *after* having installed another subset of the File Server role services.

Go to:

1. Server Manager
2. Roles
3. Scroll down to File Services
4. Select "Add Role Services"
5. Complete the Add Role Services wizard with the desired DFS components checked

To install the DFS Management tools:

1. Server Manager
2. Features
3. Select "Add Features"
4. Navigate to:

   - Remote Server Administration Tools

     - Role Administration tools

       - File Services Tools

         - Check "DFS System Tools"